# Wordpress: how the bleep can git-pulling the theme directory change the blog content?

Tags: wordpress, git

I have two Wordpress theme development environments, one local (WAMP) and one on a remote server. The themes directory has a clone in both wp-content folders, linked by a headless commit elsewhere on the server.

The remote WordPress and the local WordPress had different content, menus, title, and tagline.

I just did a push from the local, and ssh'ed into the remote and did a pull. **After the pull -- the remote had the SAME  content, menus, title, and tagline as the local.** (And yes, I had looked at the remote site right before doing the pull, and it had the different content).

**How is this possible,** when the Themes directory is the only thing in the git repo, and blog content is stored in the database, not the theme? Based on my understanding of WordPress, this makes no sense. What am I missing?

*(Since these were both test environments, losing the content on the remote is an annoyance rather than a crisis, but I need to know why it happened.) posting this on StackOverflow rather than WordPress stack exchange, because I don't know whether this has more to do with WordPress or with git.*

**EDIT**

Unsurprisingly, my varied attempts to reproduce the problem have all failed. I must have been somehow looking at a chached version of the page right before I did the pull -- it still makes no sense, and I still don't know what happened, but it must have been some snafu at my end.

Comment: Weird, unless you hard coded the title, tags and content into the themes it should not change the WP content after a theme change

Comment: That's what I thought, but no, I didn't hardcode anything =^/  I'm baffled as to how I could have *accidentally* uploaded data to the remote server.

Comment: for sure doing a git pull which only changes the theme files, would not change anything in the database itself. Have you checked the actual database via phpmyadmin? did the data actually change?

Comment: Yup, I checked it, and it's the same now. Granted, I didn't check the remote MySQL before I did the pull (just the visible website), so it's hypothetically possible that the content could already have changed and I was just seeing some kind of cached version. But that still begs the question of how I could have accidentally uploaded a new set of content to the remote, when I don't have anything set up to do so automatically. -- I'm going to play around and try to reproduce it, to see if I can figure out what I did when.